# create JSON using JSONCOVERTER

Tags: json, vba, outlook

I am wondering to create a json from VBA Outlook to export email as ticket on Osticket System
Everithing working well except when there's multiple attachments

I need to have this syntax

```json
{
 "alert": "true",
 "autorespond": "true",
 "source": "API",
 "name": "Angy User",
 "email": "Angry@somewhere.com",
 "subject": "Help",
 "topicId": "1",
 "message": "data:text/html,</body></html>Please Help</body></html>",
 "attachments": [
  {   "MyFile.png": "data:image/png;base64,JVBERi0........."  },
  {   "MyFile.png": "data:image/png;base64,JVBERi0........."  },
 ]
}
```

But using my code i get this

```json
{
 "alert": "true",
 "autorespond": "true",
 "source": "API",
 "name": "Angy User",
 "email": "Angry@somewhere.com",
 "subject": "Help",
 "topicId": "1",
 "message": "data:text/html,</body></html>Please Help</body></html>",
 "attachments": [
  {   "MyFile.png": "data:image/png;base64,JVBERi0.........",  
      "MyFile.png": "data:image/png;base64,JVBERi0........."  },
 ]
}
```

I use this to create the json

```vb
   Dim Body As New Dictionary

   
   Body.Add "alert", "true"
   Body.Add "autorespond", "true"
   Body.Add "source", "API"
   Body.Add "name", myMsg.SenderName
   Body.Add "email", FromAddress
   Body.Add "subject", myMsg.Subject
   Body.Add "topicId", CStr(rubriq)
   Body.Add "message", "data:text/html," & strData 'myMsg.HTMLBody
   Body.Add "attachments", Array(Attm1) 'attachments
   
   Dim json As String
   json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Body, Whitespace:=" ")
```

Where the Attm1 is a dictionary  filled in FOR loop

```
Attm1.Add oFile.FileName, "data:" & _
    oFile.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_TYPE) & _
    ";" & "base64," & n.nodeTypedValue
```

I used this function

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

The loop code

```
      Dim attachments As New Collection

   
 
   If myMsg.attachments.Count > 0 Then
      
      Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            
      Set nAtt = xmlTicket.createElement("attachments")
      nodeTicket.appendChild nAtt
      
      For i = 1 To myMsg.attachments.Count
         Set oFile = myMsg.attachments.Item(i)
         
         'I only add attachments up to a limit in size
         If oFile.Size <= MAX_ATTACHMENT Then
            sTmpFile = fs.GetTempName
            oFile.SaveAsFile sTmpFile
            
                     
            'Attachment data is always base64-coded
            n.dataType = "bin.base64"
                     
            'The ADODB.Stream tweak allows to read binary files
            Set data = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            data.Type = 1 'Binary
            data.Open
            data.LoadFromFile sTmpFile
            'MSXML will base64-code it for us
            n.nodeTypedValue = data.Read
            
            'Using the bin.base64 structure means adding namespace'd attributes.
            'For some reason, osTicket will complain for each extra attribute, so
            'we get to clean up
            n.Attributes.removeNamedItem "dt:dt"
           

            
            'For some reason, getting the content-type is very unclear in Outlook
            Set a = xmlTicket.createAttribute("type")
            a.Value = oFile.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_TYPE)
            n.Attributes.setNamedItem a
  
  
            Dim Attm1 As New Dictionary
            Attm1.Add oFile.FileName, "data:" & oFile.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_TYPE) & ";" & "base64," & n.nodeTypedValue
         
            Kill sTmpFile
            
            
         End If
      Next
       
     
   End If
```

Comment: You need one Dictionary per attachment

Comment: Thank you your right any idea how to do it ?

Comment: In a loop?  Maybe you could include more of the relevant code.

Comment: Start with `Body.Add "attachments", New Collection` then create one dictionary per attachment and add them all to the Collection.

Comment: Looks like the questions is not related to Outlook, that is how to deal with JSON in VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank You For helping Will Try This In fact i'm adding the variables after the loop may be i must do it before

Comment: Are you also creating an XML version of the message?  Or is that just for the Base64 conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.  It's easier to manage if you split out the various jobs into separate methods.

```vb
Const MAX_ATTACHMENT As Long = 500000 'or whatever

Sub MainSub()
   Dim Body As Object, dict As Object, i As Long, json As String
   Dim myMsg As Outlook.MailItem
   
   '...
   '...
   Body.Add "attachments", New Collection

   If myMsg.attachments.Count > 0 Then
      For i = 1 To myMsg.attachments.Count
         Set dict = AttachmentDict(myMsg.attachments.Item(i))
         If Not dict Is Nothing Then  'check conversion happened
            Body("attachments").Add dict
         End If
      Next
   End If
   
   json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Body, Whitespace:=" ")
   
   '...
   '...
   
End Sub

'create a dictionary from an attachment if it meets the size limit
Function AttachmentDict(att As Outlook.Attachment)
    Dim dict As Object, fso As Object, sTmpFile As String
    If att.Size < MAX_ATTACHMENT Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sTmpFile = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & fso.GetTempName
        att.SaveAsFile sTmpFile
        dict.Add att.Filename, "data:" & _
          att.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_TYPE) & _
          ";" & "base64," & FileToBase64(sTmpFile)
        Set AttachmentDict = dict
    End If
End Function

Function FileToBase64(FilePath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded
    Dim objXML, objDocElem, objStream
    ' Open data stream from file
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile FilePath
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()
    FileToBase64 = objDocElem.Text
End Function
```

Comment: Did not expect a very helpful response like this !! Thank Youuu Will try it and post reponse

Comment: Edited the `AttachmentDict` method to add the correct value to the dictionary....

Comment: Willams That's working !! you saved me days for solution man thank you again

Comment: OK good to hear.